# how to properly define node / express routes in a Node / Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Just spent entire day (!) dealing with this issue:

In my Node /Express / Angular app, I have this simple Node routing:

server.js:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config
var morgan   = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(database.url);     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request


// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

route.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
    });
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DC Quote</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-view></div>

<script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script  src="../bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script  src="../bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
<script  src="../app/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main Angular app module:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'angularFileUpload'
]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/Quote', {templateUrl: "tabcontrol/tabcontrol.html", controller: 'TabController'})
          .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Quote'});
    }])
    .controller("TabController", ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      console.log("This is TabController");
      var setAllInactive = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          workspace.active = false;
        });
      };

      var Site = {
        numberOfMainframes: undefined,
        numberOfStorageFrames:  undefined,
        numberOfUnixServers:  undefined,
        numberOfBladeCenters: undefined,
        numberOfX86Servers: undefined
      };

      var addNewWorkspace = function() {
        var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
        $scope.workspaces.push({
          id: id,
          name: "Site " + id,
          active: true
        });
      };

      $scope.workspaces =
          [
            { id: 1, name: "Site 1" ,active:true  },
            { id: 2, name: "Site 2" ,active:false  }
          ];

      $scope.addWorkspace = function () {
        setAllInactive();
        addNewWorkspace();
      };

      $scope.removeWorkspace = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          if(workspace.active){
            var index = $scope.workspaces.indexOf(workspace);
            console.log('Active Workspace id: ' + index);
            $scope.workspaces.splice(index,1);
          }
        })
      };

      $scope.collectValuesFromEachTab = function(){

        $scope.quote = new Object();
        $scope.quote.SalesForceId = $scope.salesForceId;
        $scope.quote.AccountName = $scope.accountName;
        $scope.quote.siteCollection = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
          //console.log("Site: " + workspace.name);
          //console.log("Number of Mainframes: " + workspace.numberOfMainframes);
          //console.log("Number of Starage Frames" + workspace.numberOfStorageFrames);
          //console.log("Number of Unix/AIX Servers: " + workspace.numberOfUnixServers);
          //console.log("Number of Blade Centers: " + workspace.numberOfBladeCenters);
          //console.log("Number of x86 Servers: " + workspace.numberOfx86Servers);

          var site = new Object();
          site.SiteName = workspace.name;
          site.NumberOfMainframes = workspace.numberOfMainframes;
          site.NumberOfStorageFrames = workspace.numberOfStorageFrames;
          site.NumberOfUnixServers = workspace.numberOfUnixServers;
          site.NumberOfBladeCenters = workspace.numberOfBladeCenters;
          site.NumberOfX86Servers = workspace.numberOfx86Servers;

          $scope.quote.siteCollection.push(site);
        });
        var res = $http.post('http://10.211.55.26:8081/api/dcquote/testquote', $scope.quote);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.message = data;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });
      }

    }])
    .controller("TabsChildController", ['$scope',function($scope){

    }])
    .controller('FileUploadController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
      var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'http://10.211.55.26:8081/api/test/files'
      });

      // FILTERS

      uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
          return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
      });

      // CALLBACKS

      uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
      };
      uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
      };
      uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
      };
      uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
      };
      uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
      };
      uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
      };
      uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
      };
      uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
      };

      console.info('uploader', uploader);
    }]);
```

With this routing : "app.get(*, function(){}..."

I Express is trying to just serve index.html, so my JS stuff gets clobbered, and I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-file-upload.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

However, when I change the routing to be like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {}...
```

none of my JS scripts are being found, and I get 404 trying to load each single one of them:

```
GET /bower_components/angular/angular-bootstrap.js 404 0.719 ms - 58
GET /bower_components/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js 404 1.571 ms - 72
GET /app/app.js 404 1.728 ms - 23
```

What do I need to do to configure this properly?

Comment: Is your `/bower_components` and your `/app` in your `public` folder? Because that (`public` folder) is the only thing accessible from outside, as defined by this line: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`

Comment: currently, both /bower_components, and /app are at the same level as /public

Comment: They're inaccessible then. Try putting them in the public folder

Comment: Also, it seems you have your server and client code mixed up. Since you have your routes inside your `app` as well as your `app.js` (which is supposedly client-side JS?). If that's the case you gotta separate out the client-side stuff, and put that in `public` folder where it can be accessible by the client.